# Finding the max of a list using tail recursion

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand how to write functions using tail recursion in Haskell.  In my example below, the function takes in a list and outputs the maximum value in the list. My intention is to use the `c` variable to store the current max. I was wondering if someone can explain how using tail recursion would work for this instance?

```
    myMax [] c = error "max of empty list"
    myMax [x] c = x
    myMax (x:xs) c = 
                if x > myMax xs then c = x
                else myMax xs c

--currently getting a parse error
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `c = x` in the if statement?  An if statement must return a value of the same type in both branches.  It looks like you're trying to destructively modify `c` which isn't allowed in Haskell.  I'm not sure what the intent there is because even if it was allowed I don't see what the desired outcome would be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to store the current max in `c` as I compare more and more values from the list to it. When I have no more values to compare, I output the final `max` value. That was my intention, again tail recursion is confusing to me, which is why I decided to try to get some help with it.

Comment: There is no assignment statement in haskell.  You cannot assign a value to an existing variable (the term "variable" is very misleading), you can only introduce a new binding.

Comment: @pat: How is that misleading? That's exactly how the term "variable" was originally used and how it is still used in most contexts. What *is* misleading is conflating the idea of a variable with the idea of a mutable reference or memory location.

Comment: @C. A. McCann Yes, you are completely correct, it is a variable in the original mathematical sense.  Only if you are used to the notion of mutable variables in a programming language does it become misleading.  Sorry for confusing the issue!

Comment: @pat: Learning Haskell (where much more must be explicit) has made me painfully aware of how much confusion is caused in other languages by not clearly distinguishing references, storage locations, and what immutability does or does not mean. In this case, I really think borrowing some of the mathematicians' precision makes it easier to speak and reason about what a program is doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple things to think about here.  First You don't want the user to have to enter some beginning value, so we want a function that takes only a list as its parameter.  Since you want a tail recursive implementation we do need a function that takes a second parameter though, so we'll create an inner function named `go` which takes the current max and the remaining list.

```
myMax [] = error "Empty List"
myMax (x:xs) = go x xs  -- Initialize current max to head of list.
  where
    -- go takes the current max as the first argument and the remaining list
    -- as the second.
    -- m is the current max, if there are no more elements it is the max.
    go m [] = m 
    -- Otherwise we compare m to the current head.
    -- If the head (y) is greater than m it becomes the current max.
    go m (y:ys) = if m > y then go m ys else go y ys
```

Note that we never changed the value of any variable here.  We update the current max value
by passing it as a parameter to the next step in the function.  This is critical to understand in Haskell because mutating variables is not allowed.

Comment: I had basically the same answer prepared!  I would have factored out the recursive `go` as:
`go m (y:ys) = go (if m > y then m else y) ys`, or even `go m (y:ys) = go (max m y) ys`, but taken to an extreme, you just get `myMax = maximum`.

Comment: @Andrew Myers Agree to disagree with you on that, its unconventional, but rewarding:) One question, how does `go x xs` on the very top initialize current max to the head of the list, without any `=` assignment?

Comment: Because we're carrying our current maximum value as the first parameter to `go`.  So to "initialize" the value we pass it as the first parameter to `go`.  The important thing to grok here is that every call of `go` is a new stack frame with no access to other `go` stack frames or their values.

Comment: @pat That's true, I was trying to find the balance between clarity and `myMax = maximum` as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the normal tail recursive versions of minimum or maximum, that is, the accumulator as parameter. More specifically, the accumulator parameter's initial value must be supplied from the list, the first item of the list, that is the second parameter of the the function and in which you what to find the minimum or maximum.
Restated, a min or max tail recursive function must normally take two parameters. The first parameter is the accumulator, the second is the list to analyze. The problem is the initial value of the first parameter. It cannot be supplied except from the list to be analyzed.
Next the basis of a tail recursive function is the accumulator.
The accumulator is where the last min or max value is stored and passed to the the function to compare to the next value of the list.
A basic function could be

```
fix (\f v (x:xs) -> if xs == [] then v else if x < v then f x xs else f v xs) 9999999 [6,5,4,3,2,1,10,7,8]
```

The first parameter is a guess at a value higher than any in the list and is destined to fail and cannot be automated. The first parameter should come from the list, perhaps the first item. The first parameter in the preceeding function is 'v'. It carries the last min or max value.
It is easy to use another call to the preceding function.

```
t= \(y:ys) -> (fix (\f v (x:xs) -> if xs == [] then v else if x < v then f x xs else f v xs) y ys)
```

The first part uses pattern matching (y:ys) to split the supplied list into head and tail. The head becomes the initial v parameter in the called function. The tail becomes the second.
This seems convoluted and complicated to me. The accumulator initial value is the problem. It must be calculated. How can this be done? By eliminating the first parameter. Get rid of it. But we must still retain an accumulator value to pass to compare to the next value of the list. Where can we keep it? The only place possible, in the list itself.

```
minf :: (Num b, Ord b) => [b] -> b
minf [x]      = x
minf (x:xs) = if x > head xs then minf $ x : tail xs else minf xs
```

minf takes one parameter, the list to analyze for min or max. Just change the comparison sign to '<' or '>' for min or max. Also, I use this version.

```
min = fix (\f (x:xs) -> if xs == [] then x else if x < head xs then f $ x : tail xs else f xs)
```

I am only getting my feet wet in Haskell but my expectations for it are extremely high. It is the best language, ever. It is a version of the above and takes one parameter only.